# Flutter: mover index de GridView.builder automaticamente

Tags: flutter, gridview

Tengo un widget que retorna un gridview y se le pasa por parametros una funcion que es donde el builder del gridview va a buscar mas elementos cuando los necesite para dibujar. Mi problema es que cuando modifico los parametros de la funcion que le paso a ProductGridWidget en su widget padre y ejecuto un setState() el hijo  que recibe la funcion donde va a buscar en un webservice mas productos se redibuja, pero como como la primer vez que se dibujo ya cargo 20 elementos, si no doy abajo con el scroll que llegue dentro del grid a in index mayor que 20 aun no llamo a la funcion que actualice en el padre, o sea estoy viendo periodico viejo, neceisto alguna forma de resetear totalmente mi ProductGridWidget que quede totalmente nuevo.

```
class ProductGridWidget

 extends StatefulWidget {
  final int crossAxisCount;
  final Function fetchFunction;

  ProductGridWidget(
      {@required Function fetchFunction, int crossAxisCount = 2, Key key})
      : fetchFunction = fetchFunction,
        crossAxisCount = crossAxisCount,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ProductGridWidget();
}
```

En este ejemplo lo que hago es movel el index del gridview al top, con un scrollController y entonces limpio la lista de elementos cargados, para obligarlo a rellamar la funcion para cargar los 20 primeros de nuevo.

```
class _ProductGridWidget extends State<ProductGridWidget> {
  List<Completer<Product>> productCompleters = List<Completer<Product>>();
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    fun = widget.fetchFunction;   
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
  return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: widget.crossAxisCount),
      itemBuilder:  (BuildContext context, int index) => _buildProductGridTileWidget(index),
    )
  }

Widget _buildProductWidget(int itemIndex) { 
    --metodo que se encarga de dibujar el widget para cada index--
  }

  _completeProducts(int itemIndex) async {
    try {
      --metodo que se ecarga de buscar nuevos productos al api--
    } catch (error) {
     
    }
  }
```

Comment: con scrollcontroller te funciona? si es así, porque quieres usar otra forma?

Comment: quisiera saber si existe una mejor forma de hacerlo

Comment: Ya que el que actualiza ese widget es el padre, si estas en un State del stateful deberías sobreescribir el didUpdatedWidget y mover ese lógica ahí, para q no esté dentro del método build. Otra forma es sacando del arbol de widgets el GridView, y volver a agregarlo, otra también es un usando un Key diferente para el GridView , para cada vez q se refresca, pero son menos óptimas. La que estás usando me parece la correcta

Comment: diego edite la pregunta para mas detalles, pero de lo que me comenta arriba la opcion de sacar el grid del arbol y volver a agregarlo me parece la mas interesante, puede darme detalles, digame si entiende en si el problema con la edicion q le hice a la pregunta!!!

Comment: hmm no logro entender que es lo que quieres hacer, y que es lo que no está funcionando, yo asumo q cada vez que tu actualizas el widget padre con nuevos elementos, este refresca el hijo, y lo unico que necesitas es mover el scroll a la posición inicial 0, para ver los más recientes, es eso?

Comment: el widget padre es un scafold en el body pinta un ProductGridWidget a este se le pasa una funcion que le dice al gridView donde tiene que buscar mas elementos cuando vayan movendo el scroll abajo, el problema es que cuando en el padre yo le cambio parametros a la funcion y aplico un setState se redibuja mi ProductGridWidget, pero los elementos que ya guardo que ya cargo, siguen dibujados ahi, y no se llaman nuevos con los nuevos params hasta que no llego a un index mayor a los que tengo guardados, o sea necesito se redibuje completo, de hecho redibujar no, seria mejor crearlo en si desde 0.

Comment: volvi a actualizar la pregunta, que aca en los comentarios no se puede escribir mucho

Answer (score 1):

Ok, la alternativas que tienes son sacar del widget tree al `GridView` o generar un nuevo `key` para que Flutter vuelva a crear el widget, esto último lo puedes hacer simplemente agregando el atributo `key`.

```dart
    return GridView.builder(
      key: Key('mi_nuevo_key'),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder:  (BuildContext context, int index) => _buildProductWidget(index),
    );
```

OJO: que cada key debe ser diferente para que vuelva a recrearlo, para probar intenta ponerle la hora ahí.

```dart
key: Key(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString())
```

**UPDATE**

Si deseas sacarlo del árbol de widget necesitarás agregar unas validaciones extras:

Primero declara una variable `bool` en el state.

```dart
bool completed = true;
```

sobreescribe el método `didUpdateWidget` del State con lo siguiente.

```dart
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(YourStatefulWidget oldWidget) {
    completed = false;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        completed = true;
      });
    });
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

Y al momento de pintar el `GridView` agregas la validación:

```dart
completed ? GridView(...) : const SizedBox() ,
```

Con eso estarás removiendo del árbol de widget cada vez que hay un update del parent.

Comment: y la variante de sacarlo del arbol de widgets como seria?? quisiera probar esa, pq la de generar un nuevo key por cada uno una vez lo redibuje me quedan dudas q pasa con los anteriores que ya genere

Comment: ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: lo probe, y no me funciona como necesito, de hecho no creo q lo este desmontando del arbol y volviendolo a poner, si se ejecuta el didUpdateWidget() cuando ejecuto el setState en el padre eso lo verifique pero la lista de elemtos cargados siegue siendo la misma, y widget SnakeButton que recibe me dice que no sabe q es, que pudiera estar pasando?

Comment: ya actualicé , en realidad ese `SnakeButton` debería ser el nombre de tu statefulwidget, que error te sale?

Comment: na que no sabia que era el SnakeButton, lo subtitui por ProductGridWidget, el esta funcionando bien, pero la lista de elementos ya cargados son la que no cambia, pero le puse en el setSate dentro de didUpdateWidget: "productCompleters = [];" y funciona perfecto, pero no se supone que si lo estuviera quitando y volviendo a poner todo eso comience de 0??

Comment: en teoría al hacer lo que está dentro del didUpdateWidget, debe sacar el widget, poner un widget vacío y luego vuelve a insertar el GridView, pero los objetos que recibe tu widget son los que dependen del future, puedes llamar dentro de setState a esto :  fun = widget.fetchFunction;

Comment: te dejo mi canal de youtube donde toco temas un poco mas avanzados/intermedios de flutter : https://youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: "The framework always calls build after calling didUpdateWidget, which means any calls to setState in didUpdateWidget are redundant." esto esta en la doc y segun entiendo es precisamente lo que estamos haciendo en esta solucion, es reduntante entonces lo q hacemos??? pero funciona bien? pq lo dicen? muchas gracias por su tiempo realmente

Comment: el setState lo estoy poniendo dentro de  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback,  que es cuando el widget ha terminado de mostrarse, no directamente dentro del didUpdateWidget, lo cual está bien