# Flutter: generar manualmente el key de un widget

Tags: flutter

Que sucede con el widget hijo (ProductGridWidget) dentro de un widget padre (GridResultsView) si cuando ejecutamos un setState() en el padre autogeneramos el atributo key del hijo. Se elimina totalmente el anterior y se crea un hijo nuevo en el arbol de widgets? Como funciona exactamente este mecanismo, mi mayor duda no es que se cree un widget hijo totalmente nuevo, es que sucede exactamente con el anterior.

```
class GridResultsView extends StatefulWidget { 
  List<String> products = ['Ajo','Cebolla','Pepino','Tomate']; 

  GridResultsView({    
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _GridResultsView();
}

class _GridResultsView extends State<GridResultsView> {  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Resultado de las busqueda"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ProductGridWidget(
          key: Key(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString())),
          products: widget.products
    );
  }
```

Comment: Lo mejor es que puedas agregar un código de ejemplo para que simules el escenario que mencionas, luego usa un print(this.toString()) en el método build, para que veas si la instancia es la misma o diferente.

Comment: @diegoveloper esta pregutna tiene que ver con esta otra [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379168/flutter-mover-index-de-gridview-builder-automaticamente], ahi le pongo ejemplo en codigo